# Email doesn't receive when account locking

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 Identity server 5.11.0 server. I set up account locking using [1]. Even though the account was locked, I didn't receive any email.But when I unlock the same account from management console, I received an email.

deployment.toml configs

```
[event.default_listener.identity_mgt]
priority= "50"
enable = false
[event.default_listener.governance_identity_mgt]
priority= "95"
enable = true

[identity_mgt.account_locking]
enable_account_locking=true
allowed_failed_attempts=3
auto_unlock_time_increment_ratio=2
auto_unlock_after=15

[identity_mgt.user_onboarding]
ask_password_from_user= true
enable_email_verification = true
lock_on_creation=true

[output_adapter.email]
from_address= "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
username= "xxxxxx"
password= "xxxxx"
hostname= "smtp.gmail.com"
port= 587
enable_start_tls= true
enable_authentication= true
```

Do I need to add another configs to receive an email when locking the account?

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/locking-a-specific-user-account/

Comment: Did you try both scenarios `failed login attempt based account locking` and `lock the account by admin navigating to the management console`? Do you see any error logs printed in the carbon console(terminal) when account locking ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you lock the user account? According to the [this](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-account-lock/blob/master/components/org.wso2.carbon.identity.handler.event.account.lock/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/handler/event/account/lock/AccountLockHandler.java#L606) the email will not be sent if the user is in one of the following state.

- PENDING_SELF_REGISTRATION
- PENDING_EMAIL_VERIFICATION
- PENDING_LITE_REGISTRATION

Cheers,
Isura.